# How to call 3 threads sequentially many times?

Tags: c++, c, windows, multithreading

How to call 3 threads sequentially many times? For example: In iteration 1, execution order should be "Thread0->thread1->thread2" then in iteration 2 should be same i.e "Thread0 -> thread1->thread2" and so on. The sample code is just executing 3 threads only once. It is not going to 2nd iteration.

```
    Thread0 = CreateThread( NULL,0,ThreadProc0, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &ThreadID);
    Thread1 = CreateThread( NULL,0,ThreadProc1, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &ThreadID);
    Thread2 = CreateThread( NULL,0,ThreadProc2, NULL, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &ThreadID);

    for(i=0;i<iterations;i++)                //Iterations in calling threads
    {
        ResumeThread(Thread0);
        WaitForSingleObject(Thread0, INFINITE);
        ResumeThread(Thread1);
        WaitForSingleObject(Thread1, INFINITE);
        ResumeThread(Thread2);
        WaitForSingleObject(Thread2, INFINITE);
    }

    // Close thread and semaphore handles
```

Comment: Why is that the first thing everybody tries to do with threads is to completely defeat the entire point of threads?! (Your question seems to be based on a number of misunderstandings. For example, what do you think it means to "call 3 threads"? You call functions. It doesn't mean anything to "call" a thread.)

Comment: David.. i know i am not utilizing the strength of threads but just wanted to know how this will work? Call a thread means call that thread function only..

Comment: What do you mean by "call that thread function"? What is a "thread function"? Do you mean the function that a thread runs when it starts? If so, the thread calls that function itself when it starts.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i am new to multi-threading.. Just trying to achieve this.. please suggest me how to achieve this :)

Comment: I honestly still don't know what "this" is. If you're new to multi-threading, why not learn how to use them the way they're normally used first? And then you can learn crazy things like calling threads, suspending them, or forcing them to run in a particular sequence for no particular reason later once you understand the basics. If you want a thread to do some task, make a function to do that task, and then call `CreateThread` passing that function as the start function. Master that first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the concept. `ResumeThread` means to **re-start** the thread, **not** re-run the thread proc from the beginning. It just *resume* the proc from where it is stopped previously.

Basically there are two ways.

1. Create new threads in each iteration.
2. Rewrite your thread proc to live "forever" and sync with it using events.

Refer to here: [How to restart threads?](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1206882)

Answer (score 1):

When you call `WaitForSingleObject()` with a thread handle, you are waiting for the thread to finish running (when it returns from its thread proc). After it has finished, `ResumeThread()` will have no further effect.

Comment: But after waiting for thread0 to finish running, i need to resume thread1. For that i used ResumeThread(). But my question is with for loop, why thread0/thread1/thread2 are not executing multiple times?

Comment: @Hello: `WaitForSingleObject` is signled only when the thread function finishes, how would you expect it run again?

Comment: What should i do in order to call thread0 after thread2 in next iteration?

Comment: @Hello: I'm wondering if you might have some fundamental misunderstanding about how threads work. Perhaps you think a thread runs its start function and then waits for you to tell it to run it again? If so, no, a thread runs its start function and when that function returns, it terminates. If you want to write a loop that waits for a condition before repeating, you can. But it won't happen unless you code it.

Comment: @Hello: You say things like "call thread0" but that doesn't make any sense. You don't call threads. If you want to start/run a thread, call `CreateThread`. If you want to write code to make a thread that waits for you to tell it to do things and then it does them in a loop or repeating, then you have to actually write that code.

Answer (score 1):

You should look into using Events to synchronize the threads iinstead of ResumeThread.